# QSqlRelationalTableModel - proper way to check if contains value

Tags: c++, qt

What is the proper way to check if a certain column of a QSqlRelationalTableModel contains a certain value? If I have a `QSqlRelationalTableModel* tableModel`, and I'd like to check if the first column contains the `QString string = "hello"` string? Should I just loop through the items, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities (probably somebody will correct me if there are more).

1. you could iterate through the column and check every instance for `hello` ?
2. you could use a filter like https://forum.qt.io/topic/19079/search-bar-for-qsqltablemodel-in-qtableview/4

The sample code from that link is

```
model->select();

QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(model);
proxy.setFilterWildcard(searchText);
```

I admit I did not test this code at all, just happened to stumble upon it whilst Googling, but I hope it can help you to find a correct solution?